# Kendo Multiselect in Popup Window returns null values for added items

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

```
<div style="padding-right: 73px">
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.DisciplinesID)
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .Value(Model.DisciplineSelectedList)
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetDisciplines", "Patron", new { id = Model.Id }))
        )
        .Placeholder("Select Disciplines...")
    )
    </div>
```

When selecting new items from dropdown the value added to the ID's List has a value of null

Comment: After the rendering when you inspect the multi-selector items do they have value?

Comment: Yes each item has it's own individual value, which is loaded with text value from database

<select id="DisciplinesID" multiple="multiple" name="DisciplinesID" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" data-bind="value:DisciplinesID" style="display: none;"><option value="1" selected="">Timing</option><option value="2" selected="">Recovery</option>

Comment: Do you mean "Value" field? Your code seems to be ok.